# Search and replace substring with an other in all the files of a folder and all its subfolders

Tags: string, replace

I know there are several questions as this one, but mine is specific:

I want to replace the substring: `localhost:8000/` with `https://www.begueradj.com/` in all the HTML files existing in a folder and its sub folders.

The `/` and `//` are causing me problems in this situation.

Any hints?

**Edit:**

The attempt I tried to work more on is the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758963/find-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories/31594772#31594772).

But ***any*** other effective approach is welcome.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your approach (`sed`, `find`, etcetera)?

Comment: All you need to do is use different delimters for the sed `s///` command: for example`s@http://localhost:8000/@https://www.begueradj.com/@`

Comment: Also, I see you have fancy curly quotes for the sed body. Take care to use simple plain quotes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two things to improve here:

- using `for` on a list of file names generated by another command tends to break in rather interesting ways if file names contain space characters or worse
- the quotes you use in `sed` are odd

Try

```
find . -name '*.html' -print0 | 
    xargs -0 sed -i 's|localhost:8000|https://www.begueradj.com/|'
```

The `-print0` option of `find` will make sure that all names passed to `xargs` are NUL-terminated.

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting this : `sed: no input files
`

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Ups, sorry, try again

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ If it still doesn't work: Does `find . -name '*.html' -print` return anything? If not your HTML files don't end in `.html`.